# Filter authorized data in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a question about Authorize control in ASP.NET Core. So... if I have a system like a big company with many projects and employees. I'm using token access to login.

Users:

```
public int Id {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
public ICollection<Project> Projects {get; set;}
```

Projects:

```
public int Id {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
public ICollection<User> Users {get; set;}
```

I have an endpoint that'll show my users a project detail using its id: `GET ...api/projects/{id}`.

My website shows only the ones the user is allowed to see but... I want to prevent users from accessing the projects information directly through the api url..

e.g.:
UserA have access to Project1 only. But could get Project2 information using: `GET ...api/projects/2` directly. Is there a way to block the access?

Comment: Best option is to have some token issuer for example Identity Server. Link: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/. With this, you can restrict users from having access to resources(APIs, etc..) without first being authenticated and authorized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. I found a way and here it is:

I was already using `[Authorize("Bearer")]` on my controller. So I'm able to use the token to get some info. So I added a claim with projects Ids using a ManyToMany table. This was made inside my token configuration class:

```
foreach (var userProject in user.Projects)
{
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim("projects", UserProject.ProjectId.ToString()));
}
```

So I added this to my controller:

```
var projects = User.FindAll("projects");

List<int> userProjectIds = new List<int>();

foreach (var project in projects)
{
    userProjectIds.Add(Int32.Parse(project.Value));
}
```

This way, I have a list of Ids from the projects the user have access to.

Then in my repository to filter the projects I created method that uses the List list and creates a filtered List:

```
List<Project> projectsList = _context.Projects
                                     .Where(p => userProjectIds.Contains(p.Id))
                                     .ToList();
```

And this is it. I then return this list to my user. 
I hope this helps anyone.

edit: Just to be clearer, I do not return the list itself, only use it to evaluate if the user is suitable to access the project